# To deduct amount starting with the smallest until amount is exhausted

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL table that looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp_Supply 
(
    Supplier_Name Varchar(30), 
    Invoice_Number Varchar(20), 
    Amount Money
)

INSERT INTO #Temp_Supply (Supplier_Name, Invoice_Number, Amount)
    SELECT 'Supply1', 'Inv1', 1000 UNION
    SELECT 'Supply1', 'Inv2', 2000 UNION
    SELECT 'Supply1', 'Inv3', 3000 UNION
    SELECT 'Supply2', 'Inv1', 1500 UNION
SELECT 'Supply2', 'Inv2', 2500
    
CREATE TABLE #Temp_Supply_Deduction
(
    Supplier_Name Varchar(30), 
    Deduction_Amount Money
)

INSERT INTO #Temp_Supply_Deduction(Supplier_Name, Deduction_Amount)
    SELECT 'Supply1', 2500 UNION
SELECT 'Supply2', 500
    
SELECT * FROM #Temp_Supply
SELECT * FROM #Temp_Supply_Deduction
```

While selecting the supply table To deduct the Hold amount starting with the smallest Invoice Number until the amount is exhausted

The excepted output should be

| Supplier_Name | Invoice_Number | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Supply1 | Inv1 | 0.00 |
| Supply1 | Inv2 | 500 |
| Supply1 | Inv3 | 3000 |
| Supply2 | Inv1 | 500.00 |
| Supply2 | Inv2 | 2500.00 |

Thanks

Comment: Please explain how do you get the `Amount` in the expected result

Comment: Tried with below query it will affect by available row only <br> ;With CTE AS
 (
  Select a.*, ROW_NUMBER() Over (Partition By a.Supplier_Name Order By a.Supplier_Name, a.Invoice_Number) As Serial_No, b.Deduction_Amount
   From #Temp_Supply a
    Inner Join #Temp_Supply_Deduction b On a.Supplier_Name = b.Supplier_Name
   
 )
 Select a.*, Amount - Deduction_Amount
  From CTE a
  Where (Amount - Deduction_Amount) > 0

Comment: Please [edit] any clarifications directly into your question.

Comment: Do you want to deduct from invoices starting with the smallest invoice no and continue until all deduction amount is exhausted?

Comment: yes exactly, suppose my deduction amount is 500, it will reduce only in  inv1

Comment: my deduction amount is 1500, it will reduce from inv1 is 1000 and inv2 is 500

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use window function `sum() over (partition by  ... order by ...)` to get the cumulative sum of `Amount`. Use `CASE` expression to conditionally check for `Deduction_Amount` against the cumulative sum amount to determine the balance amount

```
select d.Supplier_Name, 
       d.Deduction_Amount, 
       s.Invoice_Number, 
       Invoice_Amount = s.Amount,
       Balance = case when  d.Deduction_Amount
                      >=    sum(s.Amount) over (partition by d.Supplier_Name 
                                                order by s.Amount, 
                                                         s.Invoice_Number)
                      then  0
                      when  d.Deduction_Amount 
                      >=    sum(s.Amount) over (partition by d.Supplier_Name 
                                                    order by s.Amount, 
                                                             s.Invoice_Number)
                      -     s.Amount
                      then  sum(s.Amount) over (partition by d.Supplier_Name 
                                                    order by s.Amount, 
                                                             s.Invoice_Number)
                      -     d.Deduction_Amount
                      else  s.Amount
                      end
from   #Temp_Supply_Deduction d
       inner join #Temp_Supply s on d.Supplier_Name = s.Supplier_Name
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5921002fabcfaeeeb22696e0b11e0245)

By the way, your expected output in the question is wrong

Should be

| Supplier_Name | Deduction_Amount | Invoice_Number | Invoice_Amount | Balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Supply1 | 2500.0000 | Inv1 | 1000.0000 | 0.0000 |
| Supply1 | 2500.0000 | Inv2 | 2000.0000 | 500.0000 |
| Supply1 | 2500.0000 | Inv3 | 3000.0000 | 3000.0000 |
| Supply2 | 500.0000 | Inv1 | 1500.0000 | 1000.0000 |
| Supply2 | 500.0000 | Inv2 | 2500.0000 | 2500.0000 |

Comment: Thanks. Yes Agreed. But for the supply1 deduction amount is  2500 as per output Balance for inv1 is correct but inv2 should 500 instead of 1500.
Total Invoice Amount - deduction amount to be 500.

Comment: updated the query